# How to Boot Android system every time from single snapshot image?

Tags: android, hibernate, linux-kernel, filesystems, ext4

I am trying to reduce boot-time on Android M, Now it is taking ~8 sec. For this I used hibernation method. Every thing is fine, Android system booting every time properly if and only if I do hibernate and take snapshot image before shutting it down. But I don't want to take snapshot image every time, system should be resumed from single snapshot image.

Here I tried to resume from same single image. It works for 1st time and second time onwards i am getting ext4 file-system errors.

This partition belongs to android data partition. Error I am having from this partition is:

```html
[   64.250735] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:758: group 9, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 31166 vs 31165 free clusters
[   64.252813] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]Aborting journal on device mmcblk0p26-8.
[   64.267680] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p26): Remounting filesystem read-only
[   64.268667] <3> (1)[1:init]init: Starting service 'media'...
[   64.269479] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_free_blocks:4881: Journal has aborted
[   64.272235] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4999: Journal has aborted
[   64.278537] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4999: Journal has aborted
[   64.283132] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_ext_remove_space:3035: Journal has aborted
[   64.286970] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_ext_truncate:4669: Journal has aborted
[   64.291775] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4999: Journal has aborted
[   64.294465] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_truncate:3894: Journal has aborted
[   64.297764] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4999: Journal has aborted
[   64.300437] <3> (3)[1507:PackageManager]EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p26) in ext4_orphan_del:2888: Journal has aborted
```

I tried to understand this error, This first error is coming because of file-system meta-data mismatch in RAM and partition. i.e. My snapshot image contains mounted "/data" partition which has old file-system data in RAM, and data in the Disk Partition is updated at 2nd boot after resume from snapshot image. I am thinking this file-system data should be updated before resuming processes.

Please suggest me some way to fix the above error?

Comment: run e2fsck/fsck on the EXT4 partition which you are getting the error and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Prabhakar, for the suggestion. But e2fsck/fsck can work only if we apply on **unmounted** partition. Here above error i am getting on mounted partition.

Comment: Can you explain the steps you have taken? How did you take a snpashot? use adb command? then how did you resume? Thanks,

Comment: Hi @omkar, please let me know the steps you followed for snapshot boot in Android.